# How can i control unity process which is docked in side panel from the C# application?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, devexpress

```
        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            RunUnity();

            myManager = new MemoryMapFileHandler("testMapName", "send", "recv", 512);

            Thread readThread = new Thread(myManager.Read);
            readThread.IsBackground = true;
            readThread.Start();
        }

        public void RunUnity()
        {
            Process _unityProcess = new Process();
            _unityProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\myTestProject\TestProject.exe";
            _unityProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-parentHWND " + Unity_Panel.Handle.ToInt32();
            _unityProcess.Start();
            _unityProcess.WaitForInputIdle();

            SetParent(_unityProcess.MainWindowHandle, Unity_Panel.Handle);
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw099.gif)

This is my code and prototype UI for application.
What i want to do is, controlling Unity when it is focused.

So i made side panel via DevExpress.DockManager.
As you can see, it works fine only when it begin. (only if i didn't act anything before it is launched (mouse click, keyboard push or anything) ) But when i clicked another panel or process or window it became immediately uncontrolable, even though it is still run. I clicked side panel to try controlling it, but it doesn't work.

When i click side panel, it focused to Dock_Container of side panel.
So i thought it was problem of focus at that time. But i'm not sure about it now :(

I tried below ways but these are not works at all.

> Attach click handler to Dock_Container manually to change **Form.ActiveControl** as **Unity_Panel** when clicking side Panel.

> Attach click handler to Dock_Container manually to call **Unity_Panel.Focus()** when clicking side Panel.

> Calling **SetForegroundWindow**(Unity_Panel.Handle)

> Make MyForm as MDIContainer. Make empty form as MDI child and try to execute Unity Process in it.

Also when i lunched notepad instead of Unity Process it works well, and can be controlled again after i interacted with another elements.

All attempts were failed. Unity Process run but i can't control it whenever it lose focus once. I still don't know why. Is there any solution to fix this?